# Find virtual host for VM running Windows Server 2012 Standard (not R2)

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I can find the virtual host to all of my Windows Servers (2003-2012 R2) using this in a command line:

```
reg query "\\*MACHINENAME*\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters" /v HostName
```

However, I have one server that is running 2012 Standard and it does not have this reg key.

I verified that the server is a VM using:

```
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Model:" /c:"Host Name" /c:"OS Name"
```

However, I'd really like to know where this VM is being hosted. I've investigated other methods of determining the host, but they all focus around reading the reg key that this VM does not have for some reason.

Is there a way to determine where this VM is hosted without that reg key? We are using Hyper-V and have no reason to suspect that this VM is a one-off snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

Check the “HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Auto” mostly all the host details stored in this key at guest

There is an class [check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850169(v=vs.85).aspx) to share vm and host details

Comment: same problem. this /Auto file is also not found .. pls help ?

Comment: /Auto is not a file.   “HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Auto” is the Registry Key in the Guest Machine that provide details Host details

Comment: i went through regedit .. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\ after this only one registry is there called "(Default)"  . i need to know which physical machine is connected to my VM .. in task manager user tab .. In the client name column its shows my physical machine name but i need in batch script or power shell or any script where i can write the connection history in one text file..